# TsLint: '$http' cannot be declared in the constructor

Tags: typescript, tslint

As the title states I get the following TSLint error:

> '$http' cannot be declared in the constructor

I couldn't find anything related to this error on the internet.

Here's my code:

```
module MyModule {
    "use strict";

    class MyService {
        static $inject = ["$http"];
        constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just as I posted the question I realized I need to check my `tslint.json` file and I found this:

```
"no-constructor-vars": true,
```

Apparently, this is documented on [tslint's github page](https://github.com/palantir/tslint):

> `no-constructor-vars` disallows the public and private modifiers for
>   constructor parameters.

So the solution is simply to disable `no-constructor-vars`:

```
 "no-constructor-vars": false,
```

Comment: `no-constructor-vars` has been renamed to `no-parameter-properties`, see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/1296